# How does Java @Target annotaion declare Target annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

I'm a newbie with Java programming. While i'm learning Java Annotation, I digged a little big deeper into the declaration of @Target in JDK and i got this

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
public @interface Target {
    ElementType[] value();
}
```

What confuses me here is that @Target Annotation declares Target Annotation.
Where comes the very first @Target annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

> Where comes the very first @Target annotation ?

During compilation, the compiler finds (and defines/registers) the annotation type `Target`. It will then scan the type for annotations and find `@Target` which was already defined, so no issue.